# How to split factor names in a column within a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, split, tidyr

In the data frame (`df`), `col2` contains encoded information separated by a period like `d.MAG.5.2`. I want to split the `name` into three categories `genus`, `species`, `replicate` that in this case would correspond to `d`, `MAG`, `5.2`. Note that, I don't want to split the period of the numerics at the end.

```
col1 <- rnorm(1:3)
col2 <- c("d.MAG.1.1","d.MAG.3.4","d.TEX.5.6")

df <- data.frame(col1, col2)
```

I want the new dataset to look like this:

```
col1 <- rnorm(1:3)
genus <- c("d","d","d")
species <- c("MAG","MAG","TEX")
replicate <- c("1.1","3.4","5.6")
df <- data.frame(col1, genus, species, replicate)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tidyr::extract` you could do:

```r
library(tidyr)

df |>
  tidyr::extract(col2,
    into = c("genus", "species", "replicate"),
    regex = "^([^.])\\.([^.]*)\\.(.*)$"
  )
#>   col1 genus species replicate
#> 1    1     d     MAG       1.1
#> 2    2     d     MAG       3.4
#> 3    3     d     TEX       5.6
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(col2 = sub("(^.*)\\.(.*)\\.(\\d+\\.\\d+)", "\\1,\\2,\\3", col2)) %>% 
  separate(col2, into = c("genus", "species", "replicate"), sep=",")

       col1 genus species replicate
1 0.7264348     d     MAG       1.1
2 1.0411627     d     MAG       3.4
3 1.2302765     d     TEX       5.6
```

Comment: if using separate `separate(df2, col2, c("genus", "species", "replicate"), extra = 'merge')`

Answer (score 2):

Another method:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate(col2, into = c("genus", "species", "r1", "r2")) %>%
  unite("replicate", r1:r2, sep = ".")
#>         col1 genus species replicate
#> 1 -1.9530625     d     MAG       1.1
#> 2 -1.2879991     d     MAG       3.4
#> 3  0.8091388     d     TEX       5.6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: if using separate `separate(df2, col2, c("genus", "species", "replicate"), extra = 'merge')`

Answer (score 2):

A couple options that both use some regex:

```r
library(tidyverse)

#option 1
extract(df, 
        col2, 
        into = c("genus", "species" , "replicate"), 
        regex = "(\\w)\\.(\\w+)\\.(.*$)")
#>         col1 genus species replicate
#> 1 1.48039902     d     MAG       1.1
#> 2 0.03728211     d     MAG       3.4
#> 3 0.28125162     d     TEX       5.6

#option 2
separate(df, 
         col2,
         into = c("genus", "species" , "replicate"),
         sep = "\\.(?!\\d$)")
#>         col1 genus species replicate
#> 1 1.48039902     d     MAG       1.1
#> 2 0.03728211     d     MAG       3.4
#> 3 0.28125162     d     TEX       5.6
```

Comment: I realize now that option 1 is not really different than the solution by @stefan. Option 2, however is different than the other `separate` solutions.

Comment: `separate(df2, col2, c("genus", "species", "replicate"), extra = 'merge')`